# Does REST only cover CRUD?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I'm writing an AngularJS application that's communicating with an API, and right now that API is following the REST architecture.

I know the basics of REST, but I've still not understood if REST *only* covers the CRUD operations? For example, if I'm building a community website and I want to make it possible for people to add each other as friends, is this covered by REST in any way? What about search queries? If not, is there any other architecture that's recommended to follow, or should I roll my own?

Also, should I even be using REST for a community website? There are a lot of cases where it seems like it's not the optimal design, but when I google around I only get results saying that REST is the best practice. For example PUT /api/user/:id wouldn't be very useful, since the only user you're able to update (unless you're an admin) is yourself.

Comment: Aside from all the marketing, `REST` is basically just HTTP requests. You can implement any operation you want, any way you like.

Comment: Yes, I know. Rolling my own architecture wouldn't be any problem, but if there's any standard that is good practice to learn and follow, I prefer doing that. However I'm starting to doubt that REST is optimal in my case.

Comment: ReST is far more than just CRUD. Google "HyperMedia". That's what ReST really is about. Also read this: http://amundsen.com/hypermedia/hfactor/ - The goal is to develop clients and servers that can evolve independly. An interesting sample for HyperMedia usage is this: https://github.com/mamund/Building-Hypermedia-APIs

Comment: I should've said, *"aside from all the media hype, ..."* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends, REST is just an architectural style and (in many forms unfortunately) is used all over the world. I also follow REST rules in all type of applications but try to stay at the second level of [Richardson's Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). Why? Since I consider HAL, HATEOAS and all the API discoverability as an unnecessary buzz - unfortunately documentation is still very important.

What you need to consider while designing an API is if it's going to public or not. If it's not, you can probably whatever you want/need (of course this is not good idea). If it is going to be public the consistency starts to play a great role - API needs to be designed in such a way that it will be both intuitive and easy to use. E.g. this is not good idea to introduce new endpoint every time you need a new *operation* - thus following CRUD REST rules seems to be reasonable option. When it comes to to going beyond CRUD - yes, I've created APIs with verbs in endpoints - but it was almost always the last resort and to be honest I don't feel guilty.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is a bit too broad, but I'll try to answer.

> REST only covers the CRUD operations?

No, it covers other operations as well. You have to transform your operation into a HTTP method and a resource. The resource can have identifiers: URIs. An URI with a HTTP method compose a hyperlink. This hyperlink can be followed by the client. You can attach the operation name, etc... to the hyperlink as meta-data, so it can be used by the client to recognize the operation. At least that's how it should work.

> What about search queries?

General queries are not supported currently, because there is no standard RDF vocab which could be used to describe a general query. There are non-standard workaround, you can use them or for example a SPARQL endpoint. More fixed queries can be used with URI templates.

> Also, should I even be using REST for a community website?

As far as I know facebook uses it for 3rd party clients, so you can develop a facebook application using their REST API. Another advantage that it scales better than SOAP. If you don't need these features currently, then you can use something else you are more familiar with.